# Change div id/class onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

So let's imagine I have 2 `divs`. 
`Div1` and `Div2`

So `Div1` is displayed automatic when you land on the page. 
`Div2` should be displayed when clicking on a button in `Div1`.
This button should remove `div1` completely and put `Div2` in it. Without reloading the page or redirecting to next page. I don't know how to do it. Can someone help me out with some code?

Comment: Why you can't replace old content with new content on button click instead of creating a new Div2?

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe I did not fully understand what you need, but try something like this

**UPDATED**

HTML code

```
 <div class="box">
  <div class="one">
    <p>this is my content number 1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="two">
    <p>this is my content, which should show up when clicking button1</p>
  </div>

  <button class="button1">im a button</button>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
.one,
.two {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: pink;
}

.two {
  display: none;
  background: silver;
}
```

JQ code

```
$( '.button1' ).on( 'click', function () {
    $( '.one' ).remove();
    $( '.two' ).show();
});
```

watch demo on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/troyanvic/ggnhh5w0/)

Comment: lets imagine i have a box. in the box is div class one and two. When the button1 is clicked, the div class one should be removed out of the box and the div class two should be in there. So when the button is clicked, class two should replace class one

<div class="one">
 this is my content number 1
</div>

<div class="two">
 this is my content, which should show up when clicking button1
</div>

<button class="button1">im a button</button>

Comment: @mika look at this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/troyanvic/ggnhh5w0/1/)

Comment: oh thx man. This is nearly what im looking for. The only problem is, that there shouldnt be an empty silver box. Thats all i need. Just one red box, with text inside it, which will change after you click the button. If you could do that for me. Man thank you so much. Cant really find anything like it on the web

Comment: @mika no problem, dude. see updated demo on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/troyanvic/ggnhh5w0/)
and a little advice - learn jquery, because what you need is an elementary example